# Peer-to-peer replication - replication stored procs not created after new peer initialization

Tags: replication, sql-server-2014

I have a vexing situation where I'm trying to add a new node to peer-to-peer replication.  Replication stored procedures don't get created in the new node causing the dreaded 'stored procedure doesn't exist" error message.

The publisher is a busy OLTP database so stopping the agent is not an option.

I did the following steps:

1. Set up database A in Server A (SQL Server 2014 SP2) to be a peer-to-peer replication publisher
2. Backed up database A
3. Restored backup to database A in Server B (SQL Server 2014 SP2)
4. Performed the configure peer-to-peer steps to add Server B as the new peer, 
   selecting Option 2 in New Peer Initialization to initialize the new peer from the backup
5. Database A on Server B is now a subscriber for Server A publisher
6. Launched Replication Monitor and immediately noticed that the publisher on Server A can't execute replication stored procedure sp_XXXX because it doesn't exist in the subscriber on Server B.
7. I checked Database A on Server B and noticed it's missing all the replication stored procs it was supposed to get from the publisher.

Am I missing something or is there a bug in the peer-to-peer replication config process?  No matter how many times I repeated the process even after carefully researching to make sure I checked off every box.

Any advice is much appreciated!

Comment: Please add the tag for your DBMS and version to your question.